# Powershell script to recursively search and find file size differences

Tags: powershell, recursion, compareobject

I have code that finds if a file/folder exists or not in a different location, basically compares two folders. I cannot seem to find anything online to also search file size differences. My code is below and I just need help on how to recursively search and find file size differences as well.

```
$source = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "C:\Users\Cl\Desktop\Source"
$compare = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "C:\Users\Cl\Desktop\WMIS"
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $source -DifferenceObject $compare -PassThru
```

Comment: you want to reimplement robocopy feature to copy only changed files ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `measure-object` to compare file sizes, then if you want to do something afterwards (like copy the updated one to the destination) store them in a variable and create `if` statements accordingly. You can use `get-member` to view the properties you can use. I think this gives you the sizes in bytes so divide the results by "1GB". Try something like this:

```
$source = gci "c:\users\c1\desktop\source" -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum
#$source = ($source.sum / 1GB)

$compare = gci "c:\users\c1\desktop\WMIS" -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum
#$compare= ($compare.sum / 1GB)
```

Comment: Nice example of `Measure-Object` but this approach is highly error prone. `source` could have 1000 1MB files, `WMIS` could have 10 100MB files, and now it looks like they're the same

Comment: ^ Agree, you could loop through and create a hash table with the file names/sizes and compare them that way if you wished.